# Weird segmentation fault in C big array with clang

Tags: c, clang

Here i want to find the sum of all the primes below two million.
I use sieve of Eratosthenes so i need a two million array.

At first, i only declare the array as a global variable, but zsh give me a segmentation fault.So i tried malloc but the error still there.
I already test small array the program works fine.

Besides, i use clang-1000.10.44.2, with -O2 the program can work but the answer is incorrect.The code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXN 2000000

unsigned long long sum;
void erat(int maxn, char *flag)
{
    flag[0] = 0;
    flag[1] = 0;
    for(int i = 2; i < maxn; i++)
        if(flag[i])
            for(int j = i * i; j < maxn; j+=i)
                flag[j] = 0;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    char *flag = (char*) malloc(MAXN * sizeof(char));
    for(i = 0; i < MAXN; i++)
        flag[i] = 1;
    erat(MAXN, flag);
    for(i = 0; i < MAXN; i++)
        if(flag[i]) sum+=i;
    printf("%llu\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Hope someone can help me, thanks for your time!

Comment: OT: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`  1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful. 2) in C, the returned value has type `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: Thank u! Especially for the rule 2 :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `i` is `46349`, `i*i` is `2148229801`, this is more than fits in an integer so overflows to `-2146737495`, as this is less than `maxn`, `flag[j] = 0` is executed which is out of bounds of the array so crashes.

Changing `j` to `long long` fixes the bug:

```
for (long long j = (long long)i * i; j < maxn; j += i)
```

Comment: I think it is not good to say it "overflows to" since it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Osiris yes its undefined according to the standard but in this actual case this is the value obtained when running on a PC in the debugger and explains the observed behaviour of the rest of the program

Comment: But doesn't undefined mean that you can not rely on the outcome? You may get this result, but you also may not. Same as you not always get a segmentation fault if you write out of bounds.

Comment: Yes in theory you can't rely on the outcome but in reality as far as I know on any x86 processor if you multiply 46349 by 46349 you will always get -2146737495. The behaviour is undefined in the standard in order to not put unnecessary restrictions on compiler implementers which might not be implementable in the target CPU.

Comment: Even if signed overflow was well-defined, the large negative array index going way past the bounds of `flag` most certainly is not.

Answer (score 1):

You're overflowing an `int` here:

```
for (int j = i * i; j < maxn; j+=i)
```

Since `i` goes up to 2000000, `i*i` can be larger than 2<sup>31</sup>, resulting in overflow and [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You can address this in the outer loop:

```
for(int i = 2; i < maxn; i++)
```

You only need to check up to the square root of `maxn`, so change it to:

```
for(int i = 2; i * i < maxn; i++)
```